# Can't link COFF object to wine

Tags: gcc, linker, wine

So I've a healthy COFF binary that links well on windows - my target is to link it on linux using wine as well.

```
ld -melf_i386 /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj -o ~/traod *all dll.so files in my lib wine folder*
```

It's giving me a bunch of unresolved symbols:

```
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x18ea06): undefined reference to `EnterCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x18ea33): undefined reference to `LeaveCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x18eab7): undefined reference to `EnterCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x18ead8): undefined reference to `LeaveCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x18eb2e): undefined reference to `EnterCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x18eb8b): undefined reference to `LeaveCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x18ebde): undefined reference to `EnterCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x18ec33): undefined reference to `LeaveCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x18ec55): undefined reference to `LeaveCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x18ec8e): undefined reference to `EnterCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x18ecbc): undefined reference to `LeaveCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x18ed1c): undefined reference to `LeaveCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x18ed3e): undefined reference to `LeaveCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x18ee9b): undefined reference to `EnterCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x18ef27): undefined reference to `LeaveCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x18fba7): undefined reference to `EnterCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x18fbbd): undefined reference to `LeaveCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x18fbee): undefined reference to `LeaveCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x18fc2b): undefined reference to `LeaveCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x18fc48): undefined reference to `LeaveCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x18ff8f): undefined reference to `EnterCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x18ffa5): undefined reference to `LeaveCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x18ffc7): undefined reference to `LeaveCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19005a): undefined reference to `LeaveCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x190080): undefined reference to `LeaveCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1900c5): undefined reference to `EnterCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1900de): undefined reference to `LeaveCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x190108): undefined reference to `LeaveCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1901e7): undefined reference to `EnterCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x190207): undefined reference to `LeaveCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19022b): undefined reference to `LeaveCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1903dc): undefined reference to `EnterCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1903ea): undefined reference to `LeaveCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x190586): undefined reference to `EnterCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1905ab): undefined reference to `LeaveCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1905c3): undefined reference to `LeaveCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x190616): undefined reference to `EnterCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x190643): undefined reference to `LeaveCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19092c): undefined reference to `EnterCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19093a): undefined reference to `LeaveCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19095c): undefined reference to `EnterCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19096e): undefined reference to `LeaveCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x190bc0): undefined reference to `CreateEventA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x190bd9): undefined reference to `CloseHandle'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19101f): undefined reference to `WaitForMultipleObjects'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19110f): undefined reference to `GetCurrentThread'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x191118): undefined reference to `GetThreadPriority'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19112c): undefined reference to `SetThreadPriority'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x191148): undefined reference to `WaitForMultipleObjects'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x191166): undefined reference to `GetCurrentThread'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19116d): undefined reference to `SetThreadPriority'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1911be): undefined reference to `GetCurrentThreadId'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19126d): undefined reference to `GetLastError'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x191291): undefined reference to `GetLastError'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1912c8): undefined reference to `GetLastError'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1912de): undefined reference to `_aControlTlb'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x191e74): undefined reference to `InitializeCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x191eff): undefined reference to `DeleteCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x191f87): undefined reference to `EnterCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x191fb0): undefined reference to `LeaveCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x191fef): undefined reference to `LeaveCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x192034): undefined reference to `EnterCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19204b): undefined reference to `LeaveCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1920ab): undefined reference to `LeaveCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1920da): undefined reference to `EnterCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1920f6): undefined reference to `LeaveCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x192130): undefined reference to `EnterCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19214b): undefined reference to `LeaveCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x192c68): undefined reference to `RegCloseKey'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x192fb8): undefined reference to `RegCloseKey'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x193628): undefined reference to `RegCloseKey'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x193b8c): undefined reference to `RegCloseKey'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x193d04): undefined reference to `RegSetValueExA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x193d6c): undefined reference to `RegOpenKeyExA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x193dae): undefined reference to `RegCreateKeyExA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x193e0e): undefined reference to `RegQueryValueExA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x193f26): undefined reference to `RegCloseKey'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1940b1): undefined reference to `RegQueryValueExA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x194139): undefined reference to `RegQueryValueExA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1941d7): undefined reference to `RegSetValueExA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x194257): undefined reference to `RegSetValueExA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19a85a): undefined reference to `OutputDebugStringA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19b68c): undefined reference to `CreateFileA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19b6d4): undefined reference to `ReadFile'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19b77e): undefined reference to `CloseHandle'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19b796): undefined reference to `SetFilePointer'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19b7d4): undefined reference to `WriteFile'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19b802): undefined reference to `CloseHandle'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19bafd): undefined reference to `OutputDebugStringA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19bb19): undefined reference to `Sleep'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19bb4a): undefined reference to `OutputDebugStringA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19c069): undefined reference to `OutputDebugStringA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19c078): undefined reference to `OutputDebugStringA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19c087): undefined reference to `OutputDebugStringA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19c131): undefined reference to `WaitForMultipleObjects'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19c1c0): undefined reference to `OutputDebugStringA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19c1f4): undefined reference to `WaitForMultipleObjects'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19c53a): undefined reference to `WaitForSingleObject'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19c5b1): undefined reference to `ReleaseMutex'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19c64d): undefined reference to `WaitForSingleObject'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19c675): undefined reference to `ReleaseMutex'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19c6e2): undefined reference to `WaitForSingleObject'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19c753): undefined reference to `ReleaseMutex'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19c7e2): undefined reference to `ReleaseMutex'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19c870): undefined reference to `ReleaseMutex'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19c88d): undefined reference to `ReleaseMutex'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19c8fc): undefined reference to `WaitForSingleObject'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19c962): undefined reference to `ReleaseMutex'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19c97d): undefined reference to `ReleaseMutex'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19ce59): undefined reference to `CreateEventA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19cf7d): undefined reference to `CreateMutexA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19d0eb): undefined reference to `Sleep'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19d31f): undefined reference to `CloseHandle'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19d396): undefined reference to `CloseHandle'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19d670): undefined reference to `WaitForSingleObject'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19d6f3): undefined reference to `ReleaseMutex'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19d7c9): undefined reference to `ReleaseMutex'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19da55): undefined reference to `ReleaseMutex'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19dae0): undefined reference to `SetThreadPriority'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19dafe): undefined reference to `ResumeThread'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19dbde): undefined reference to `WaitForSingleObject'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19dc45): undefined reference to `ReleaseMutex'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19de13): undefined reference to `WaitForSingleObject'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19e31d): undefined reference to `OutputDebugStringA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19e3b8): undefined reference to `ReleaseMutex'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19e4a9): undefined reference to `ReleaseMutex'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19e556): undefined reference to `Sleep'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19e5f8): undefined reference to `ReleaseMutex'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19ef76): undefined reference to `ReleaseMutex'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19f30c): undefined reference to `WaitForSingleObject'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19f33e): undefined reference to `ReleaseMutex'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19f376): undefined reference to `ReleaseMutex'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19f3a7): undefined reference to `ReleaseMutex'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19f3ee): undefined reference to `ReleaseMutex'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19f462): undefined reference to `WaitForSingleObject'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19f634): undefined reference to `ReleaseMutex'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19f6c2): undefined reference to `WaitForSingleObject'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19f72e): undefined reference to `ReleaseMutex'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19f77b): undefined reference to `ReleaseMutex'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19f7e4): undefined reference to `WaitForSingleObject'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19f8c1): undefined reference to `ReleaseMutex'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19f8db): undefined reference to `ReleaseMutex'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19f920): undefined reference to `WaitForSingleObject'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19f9d0): undefined reference to `ReleaseMutex'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19fa1a): undefined reference to `ReleaseMutex'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19fa74): undefined reference to `WaitForSingleObject'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19fbf4): undefined reference to `ReleaseMutex'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x19fc33): undefined reference to `ReleaseMutex'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1a8ccc): undefined reference to `QueryPerformanceCounter'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1a8d05): undefined reference to `QueryPerformanceCounter'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1a8d20): undefined reference to `QueryPerformanceFrequency'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1a8e49): undefined reference to `OutputDebugStringA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1ac439): undefined reference to `OutputDebugStringA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1ac48d): undefined reference to `OutputDebugStringA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1ad10f): undefined reference to `GetVersionExA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1ad2e4): undefined reference to `GetSystemDefaultLCID'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1ad2fd): undefined reference to `GetSystemDefaultLangID'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1adfb0): undefined reference to `OutputDebugStringA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1adfc1): undefined reference to `OutputDebugStringA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1ae4fd): undefined reference to `GetModuleHandleA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1b3448): undefined reference to `OutputDebugStringA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1ba6d5): undefined reference to `OutputDebugStringA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1bc0bc): undefined reference to `GetFileSize'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1bc125): undefined reference to `FlushFileBuffers'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1bc1f5): undefined reference to `CreateFileA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1bc205): undefined reference to `GetFileSize'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1bc22c): undefined reference to `MapViewOfFile'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1bc259): undefined reference to `UnmapViewOfFile'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1bc26e): undefined reference to `CloseHandle'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1bc283): undefined reference to `CloseHandle'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d13ae): undefined reference to `RaiseException'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d24a8): undefined reference to `CreateThread'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d24b2): undefined reference to `GetLastError'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d2502): undefined reference to `TlsSetValue'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d2514): undefined reference to `GetCurrentThreadId'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d2598): undefined reference to `ExitThread'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d2f26): undefined reference to `GetLocalTime'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d2f30): undefined reference to `GetSystemTime'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d34b8): undefined reference to `EnterCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d34db): undefined reference to `EnterCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d350a): undefined reference to `LeaveCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d352d): undefined reference to `LeaveCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d355a): undefined reference to `GetVersion'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d35ba): undefined reference to `GetCommandLineA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d3608): undefined reference to `GetModuleHandleA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d40ad): undefined reference to `GetLastError'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d42ff): undefined reference to `GetModuleHandleA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d4fb4): undefined reference to `TlsAlloc'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d4fdc): undefined reference to `TlsSetValue'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d4fed): undefined reference to `GetCurrentThreadId'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d5017): undefined reference to `GetLastError'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d5025): undefined reference to `TlsGetValue'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d5049): undefined reference to `TlsSetValue'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d505a): undefined reference to `GetCurrentThreadId'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d5071): undefined reference to `SetLastError'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d5094): undefined reference to `TlsGetValue'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d5114): undefined reference to `TlsSetValue'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d53c7): undefined reference to `InitializeCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d53d9): undefined reference to `EnterCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d564f): undefined reference to `WriteFile'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d569c): undefined reference to `GetLastError'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d56b4): undefined reference to `WriteFile'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d56c9): undefined reference to `GetLastError'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d57aa): undefined reference to `CloseHandle'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d57b4): undefined reference to `GetLastError'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d6073): undefined reference to `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d6085): undefined reference to `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d608d): undefined reference to `InitializeCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d60f2): undefined reference to `InitializeCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d610d): undefined reference to `EnterCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d6123): undefined reference to `LeaveCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d661d): undefined reference to `GetCurrentProcess'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d6624): undefined reference to `TerminateProcess'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d76b5): undefined reference to `SetFilePointer'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d76c2): undefined reference to `GetLastError'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d7807): undefined reference to `GetFileType'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d786a): undefined reference to `GetStdHandle'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d7878): undefined reference to `GetFileType'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d7aa5): undefined reference to `UnhandledExceptionFilter'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d7d71): undefined reference to `Sleep'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d8569): undefined reference to `ReadFile'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d8573): undefined reference to `GetLastError'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d8639): undefined reference to `ReadFile'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d8643): undefined reference to `GetLastError'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d875a): undefined reference to `FlushFileBuffers'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d8764): undefined reference to `GetLastError'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d87cb): undefined reference to `GetModuleHandleA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d880d): undefined reference to `GetVersionExA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d8842): undefined reference to `GetEnvironmentVariableA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d88a2): undefined reference to `GetModuleFileNameA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d8c46): undefined reference to `VirtualFree'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d90ae): undefined reference to `VirtualAlloc'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d913a): undefined reference to `VirtualAlloc'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d950b): undefined reference to `VirtualAlloc'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d95fa): undefined reference to `VirtualFree'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d962d): undefined reference to `VirtualFree'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d96b2): undefined reference to `VirtualFree'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1d990d): undefined reference to `VirtualAlloc'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1da4cb): undefined reference to `DeleteCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1da633): undefined reference to `GetModuleFileNameA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1da866): undefined reference to `GetEnvironmentStringsW'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1da88c): undefined reference to `GetEnvironmentStrings'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1da92b): undefined reference to `FreeEnvironmentStringsW'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1da93e): undefined reference to `GetEnvironmentStrings'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1da97c): undefined reference to `FreeEnvironmentStringsA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1daa35): undefined reference to `GetModuleFileNameA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1dab0b): undefined reference to `GetStdHandle'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1dab12): undefined reference to `WriteFile'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1db5d1): undefined reference to `CreateFileA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1db5dd): undefined reference to `GetLastError'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1db5f2): undefined reference to `GetFileType'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1db5fd): undefined reference to `CloseHandle'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1db7ad): undefined reference to `InitializeCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1db7c2): undefined reference to `EnterCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1db7cf): undefined reference to `LeaveCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1db8d0): undefined reference to `SetStdHandle'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1db94f): undefined reference to `SetStdHandle'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1db9f7): undefined reference to `InitializeCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1dba0f): undefined reference to `EnterCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1dba34): undefined reference to `LeaveCriticalSection'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1dd136): undefined reference to `EnumSystemLocalesA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1dd39a): undefined reference to `EnumSystemLocalesA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1dd48e): undefined reference to `EnumSystemLocalesA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1dd534): undefined reference to `GetUserDefaultLCID'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1dd646): undefined reference to `GetVersionExA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1dd873): undefined reference to `LoadLibraryA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1dd997): undefined reference to `SetFilePointer'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1dd9a4): undefined reference to `GetLastError'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1de0b0): undefined reference to `SetEndOfFile'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1de0ce): undefined reference to `GetLastError'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1de3cf): undefined reference to `GetLastError'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1df031): undefined reference to `SetEnvironmentVariableA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1e5265): undefined reference to `GetFullPathNameA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1e5a5f): undefined reference to `GetFullPathNameA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1e5aca): undefined reference to `GetFullPathNameA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1e93e7): undefined reference to `lstrcmpiA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1ec7c9): undefined reference to `GetModuleHandleA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1ec7d4): undefined reference to `LoadLibraryA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1fa369): undefined reference to `RegQueryValueExA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1fa374): undefined reference to `RegCloseKey'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1fa3ae): undefined reference to `GetModuleHandleA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1fa3bc): undefined reference to `LoadLibraryA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x1fa3df): undefined reference to `GetModuleHandleA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x20805d): undefined reference to `GetVersionExA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x2080c7): undefined reference to `CreateFileW'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x2080e2): undefined reference to `CreateFileA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x208107): undefined reference to `GetFileSize'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x208121): undefined reference to `MapViewOfFile'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x20812e): undefined reference to `GetLastError'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x208159): undefined reference to `UnmapViewOfFile'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x20816d): undefined reference to `CloseHandle'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x2089eb): undefined reference to `RegQueryValueExA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x208a03): undefined reference to `RegCloseKey'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x208a16): undefined reference to `RegCloseKey'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x208b97): undefined reference to `IsProcessorFeaturePresent'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x23f1fd): undefined reference to `GetModuleHandleA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x23f208): undefined reference to `LoadLibraryA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x256eac): undefined reference to `GetProcessHeap'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x256ec2): undefined reference to `GetProcessHeap'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x26f987): undefined reference to `GetConsoleMode'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x26f98d): undefined reference to `SetConsoleMode'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x26f99d): undefined reference to `ReadConsoleInputA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x26ffe1): undefined reference to `CreateFileA'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x26fff3): undefined reference to `CloseHandle'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_text+0x2700d9): undefined reference to `GetCurrentProcessId'
ld: /ntfs/traod_p4.bak.obj:(_rdata+0x2a1a8): undefined reference to `SetEvent'
```

Basically I have dissasembled a windows binary and assembled it again using ml.

I'm doing so in pursuit of debugging said binary using [rr](https://rr-project.org/). Currently if I run it under both wine and rr it is tracing the loader instead of the binary.

What am I doing wrong - which library should I add to make it work.